# Why gridview is empty and not loading from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am filling database from store procedure but it doesn't work, even debugger doesn't hit. What is the problem, why it is blank ? I have tried several times with nd without debugging but it doesn't work man.

```
protected void GridViewConductorsDevices_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable ConductorDevicesInfo = new DataTable();

            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewConductorsDevices.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);
            ViewState["ID"] = ID;
            ConductorDevicesInfo = (DataTable)ManageTransport.ManageConductorDevices.GetAssignedDevices();
            this.TextBoxID.Text = GridViewConductorsDevices.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();
            this.DropDownListConductors.SelectedValue= ConductorDevicesInfo.Rows[0]["Conductor_ID"].ToString();
            this.DropDownListDevices.SelectedValue = ConductorDevicesInfo.Rows[0]["Device_ID"].ToString();

            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewConductorsDevices" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CaptionAlign="Top"
                                CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowCommand="GridViewConductorsDevices_RowCommand"
                                Width="100%">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Conductor_ID" Visible="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Device_ID" Visible="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Conductor" HeaderText="Conductor" 
                                        ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Terminal" HeaderText="Terminal" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                   <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalDistance" HeaderText="Total Distance" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>--%>
                                    <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>--%>
                                    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="ChassisNo" HeaderText="Chassis No" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>--%>
                                    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="EngineNo" HeaderText="EngineNo" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>--%>
                                    <asp:ButtonField Text="Edit" HeaderText="Option" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"></asp:ButtonField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Above code doesn't include data binding. How do you bind data to GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Your Gridview, `<asp:GridView ID="GridViewConductorsDevices" runat="server" >` needs a datasource.

You mention a stored procedure, but it's not referenced in your posted code.

To bind data to a Gridview you need to either assign one to the GridView `DataSource` property in the code behind followed by a call to `GridViewConductorsDevices.DataBind()`

Alternatively you can provide the ID of a DataSource control to the Gridview `DataSourceID` property which will bind automatically during the Page Lifecycle.

However in either case, the event **`GridViewConductorsDevices_RowCommand`** will never get called as you have not defined a `CommandField` to trigger a row event.